# Google Cloud Compute Engine CentOS 7 Sudo command

Tags: centos7, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, sudo, google

Till Friday 12/10/2018 I was able to run sudo commands (Ex:`sudo mongodump --db iot_ac`). Today When I tried to run any command as root(sudo),i get the below message(Connected through SSH):

> We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
>   Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:
>
> 1. Respect the privacy of others.
> 2. Think before you type.
> 3. With great power comes great responsibility.
>
> `[sudo] password for platformcloudtest:`

Also not sure where I can find the password also, Please Help.

Comment: What are you doing differently?

Comment: I have been doing the same thing ,is there a way to get the password of the instance ([sudo] password for platformcloudtest)

Comment: The password is whatever you set it to.

Comment: I have not set any password !,Is there any other way to get out of this issue ..

Comment: Then you need to talk to the person who did set the password.

Comment: seems like ssh key has expired "= google-ssh {"userName":"platformcloudtest@gmail.com","expireOn":"2018-10-15T14:53:12+0000"}"

Comment: Hi, I declined the flag as it can be someone that set against you a password, it's nothing personnal against you, it's a possibility, it's why his comments was wrote as a comment and not as a answer. Are you the only admin on that server, and did you made any install that would had changed the sudo group or security surrounding it ?

Comment: By default there is NO root password on GCE instances ,I have not made any recent installation nor changed any  sudo group or security surrounding ,Single User no one has access to my account .Micheal is talking in general but not with respect to GCE so he needs to read the heading and tags before making the comment,  Anyways I have got response from google stating that "It seems that a change (maybe an update in Cloud) happened and user is longer part of the “Google-sudoers” group" , Also Google has provided a workaround.

Comment: @PremSanil: Do not flag again, there is nothing here that needs mod intervention. Don't abuse flags to have things you don't want to hear or you don't deem helpful deleted.

Comment: Also: *You* need to add all relevant details to a question. Instead of flagging an potentially helpful comment, you should have added relevant information (e.g. "I didn't set a password, and neither did anyone else").

Comment: In Google Cloud Compute Engine no one can set a sudo password and neither any one can !,GCE sudo users are handled through metadata and IAM & admin roles for your information.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that a change (maybe an update) happened and user is longer part of the “Google-sudoers” group

> This workaround helped me to solve the issue :
>
> 1.Adde a new user in IAM & admin page with Role Compute Admin , Owner
>
> 2.Once logged in just changed the the username from the Terminal Options->Change Linux Username
>
> 3.Enter the command sudo -i
>
> 4.run sudo commands without any issues.

find
more information: Please visit the [issue-tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117747895) thread of Google Cloud Platform